# Is Windows RT tablet able to receive push messages while it is in sleep mode

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, push-notification

IPad is able to receive push messages while it has screen turned off.

Is it possible to receive push messages with WinRT device in sleep mode?

I would guess it is not possible with Intel based pro models...

Note. This is quite important issue when planning for Windows RT applications. Chat application could be made if somekind of alert could be given to user. Pro models can run real Windows Desktop apps, which can alert user when running at backround...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on this whitepaper http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30703 and what i have read before, there is a connected standby..

the whitepaper talks about background tasks working as should. no mention of notifications per say but i'd imagine they should be work as well. Apps however will be in suspended state at that point

Comment: If state is connected then push messages should work for lock screen apps... But this is only for Arm devices?

Comment: Yes for Windows RT on ARM only. Atom SoC do support Connected Standby but Windows 8 on (x64/x64) does not support Connected Standby